# Prove $\lim_{x\to 4}\sqrt{x^3}=8$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$\lim_{x\to 4}\sqrt{x^3}=8$

My attempt:

Given $\epsilon>0$, choose $\delta=\min(1, \frac{\epsilon}{61})$

$|\sqrt{x^3}-8|=|\frac{(x-4)(x^2+4x+16)}{\sqrt{x^3}+8}|=|x-4||x^2+4x+16||\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3}+8}|$

If $|x-4|<1$ then $-5<x<5$

So, $|x^2+4x+16|<61$

And $|\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3}+8}|<1$

So, $|\sqrt{x^3}-8|<61|x-4|<61\delta=\epsilon$

Is this valid?

Comment: Seems good. Nice done.

Comment: Since it is the composition of continuous functions $\sqrt{x}$ and $x^3$ around $x=4$, you could as well just have substituted $x=4$ in. Continuity in a point means that the left- and right limit are the same for that point.

Answer (score 3):

The proof is good. You could avoid some steps by factoring
$$
\sqrt{x^3}-8=(\sqrt{x}-2)(x+2\sqrt{x}+4)
$$
and observe that, if $|x-4|<1$, then $|x+2\sqrt{x}+4|<5+2\sqrt{5}+4<15$ and you just need to take $|\sqrt{x}-2|<\frac{\varepsilon}{15}$; since
$$
|\sqrt{x}-2|=\left|\frac{x-4}{\sqrt{x}+2}\right|<|x-4|
$$
when $x>3$, you can take $\delta=\min(1,\varepsilon/15)$.

Comment: @GuusPalmer Fixed, thanks